# Webcams on Wordpress site not showing up in IE

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, webcam

A client of mine has an issue with their [website](http://www.woodlandresort.com/?page_id=11).  The site has several webcams that are linked via an image tag. The webcam images does not show up in IE. I'm not sure how to properly display the webcam images.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for IE you have to use the Axis Media Control

see here (http://www.axis.com/hosting/faq.htm)

Q: When I try to view the camera images, I get a warning alert from Windows. What can I do?
A: **For Internet Explorer, the default viewer is AXIS Media Control (AMC) which is an ActiveX component that needs to be installed**. You can change the viewer settings to Javascript, **or use another browser (e.g. Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox or Safari) that does not require any installations**

also here :

http://ask.metafilter.com/187212/MJPG-in-IE